# What is the name of local server use to run django App?

Tags: python, django

Django server name which is use to run app locally. As php use apache server to run app locally.

Comment: Django has its built-in server, used for debugging applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses pure python built-in server

Answer (score 1):

Django comes with [its own development server, `python manage.py runserver`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server), which you would use to develop locally.

For more production-ready deployments, a popular choice is Nginx backed by uWSGI or Gunicorn.